# Android: install non-market app

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I am trying to install a non-market app in Android. It is downloaded in: `file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/App.apk`

What I am doing is:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(uriString)).setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

where uriString is : `file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/App.apk`.

But there is an exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
```

**EDIT**

I am downloading the app using DownloadManager:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(MY_PATH_TP_APK));
Request req.setTitle("Test")
       .setDescription("Something useful.")
       .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "App.apk");
long enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);
```

After downloading:

```
_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor c = dm.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    Intent promptInstall = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setData(Uri.parse(uriString))
                    .setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    startActivity(promptInstall);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: install .apk programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this code in one of my apps and it's working fine:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download", "App.apk"));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe your code has one slash too much (file:///mnt instead of file://mnt (not sure here)).

Comment: Are you using a stock Android or is it a Samsung, HTC or whatever phone with a custom surface? Maybe they've changed the package installer's Intent?

Comment: I am using Sony ericsson, xperia arc with android 2.3.4

Comment: I am downloading the app using the DownloadManager class and trying to install it in the onReceive method. I will edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
```

with:

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
```